# Phonon Qt - play sound on button click

Tags: qt, qt-creator, phonon

I need to play a sound when a button is clicked, I have this:

```
Phonon::MediaObject *clickObject = new Phonon::MediaObject(this);
clickObject->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource("Click/sound.wav");
Phonon::AudioOutput *clickOutput = new Phonon::AudioOutput(Phonon::MusicCategory, this);
Phonon::createPath(clickObject, clickOutput);
```

and

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   clickObject->play();
}
```

but no sound is played?
Where am I wrong?
Thanks.
EDIT: It works now, it was the wrong path.

Comment: First: what backend are you using? Second: where is `click/sound.wav` is located? Thrird: what output does the application give?

Comment: The output is:

     PhononTest(23450): couldn't create slave: "Unable to create io-slave:
    klauncher said: Unknown protocol ''.

Comment: hmm. try to playback some other media file. If the message persists try rebooting the system.

Comment: I tried another wav, rebooted the system, installed gstreamer backend, but nothing works, still the same message.

Comment: It works! Sorry I'm an idiot. I wrote the wrong path in mediasource and the right path in QFile::exists. So it looked like the file exists. Thanks a lot for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the file path "Click/sound.wav" doesn't point where you think it points.

Try this before calling the setCurrentSource()-function:

```
bool exists = QFile::exists("Click/sound.wav");
```

If the Click directory is supposed to be in the same directory as your exe, create the path like this:

```
QString filePath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Click/sound.wav";
clickObject->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(filePath));
```

And I would suggest using [Qt resource system](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html). Then you would point to the sound file like this:

```
clickObject->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(":/Click/sound.wav"));
```

Comment: The file exists. The problem is probably backend. I haven't installed any. I tried to install gstreamer, but it doesn't work. How can I install some backend?

Comment: you can either compile it from source which you can get here https://projects.kde.org/projects/kdesupport/phonon or search the package manger for `phonon`

Comment: phonon backend couldn't gues media type. try QString filePath = "file://" + QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/Click/sound.wav";
clickObject->setCurrentSource(Phonon::MediaSource(filePath));

Answer (score 0):

You should at least connect the signal `stateChanged(Phonon::State, Phonon::State)` from your `MediaObject` object to a custom slot to detect errors: if the state changes to `Phonon::ErrorState` the reason of the error might be accessible through `QMediaObject::errorString()`.